# Using an OR within an AND within an IF on a PivotTables Outcome

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using PivotTables as a completeness check for the user of a model.  I want them to be able to see a big green "Complete" if both tabs have every hierarchy accounted for.  This condition will be met if two PivotTables only have (blank) of Grand Total below the header.  This is the code I currently have, which is returning a #Value! error.  Cells H6 and E6 are the first cells below the header of their respective PivotTables

```
=IF(AND(H6=OR("Grand Total","(blank)"),E6=OR("Grand Total","(blank)")),"Complete","Assign Common Names")



           Column E                 Column H

          Row Labels                Row Labels           #VALUE!    
   Row 6  (blank)                   Grand Total         
          Grand Total
```

Comment: If you want to do more advanced stuff with Excel pivot tables, consider using the free Microsoft add-on Power Pivot - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/power-pivot-powerful-data-analysis-and-data-modeling-in-excel-a9c2c6e2-cc49-4976-a7d7-40896795d045. It can sometimes do miracles :)

Comment: Hint: have a look at `GETPIVOTDATA` formula - e.g. https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-getpivotdata-function

Comment: I'm taking a look at Power Pivot right now.  The thing is, my formula worked before a blank was added.  When I tried to add the additional OR statements is when the equation went bonkers

Comment: Just like AND you have to specify the full condition in your `OR()`. So it's like: `AND(OR(H6="Grand Total",H6="(blank)"),OR(E6="Grand Total",E6="(blank)"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this formula is in an excel cell, you need to update syntax for OR/AND

eg

H6=OR("Grand Total","(blank)") --> OR(H6="Grand Total",H6="")

Kr,

W

Comment: Thank you, the syntax was indeed the issue